# Unexpected behavior with function composition

Tags: javascript, lodash

I'm writing a little utility function to convert strings from one word separation scheme to another. The overall project is using [lodash](http://lodash.com), which I know comes with stuff like `_.camelCase`, but I felt it was more extensible to not leverage those scheme-conversion helpers.

The idea is that other developers can easily add their own scheme definition to the ones I already have:

```
const CASES = [

    {name: 'lower_kebab', pattern: /^[a-z]+(_[a-z]+)*$/g,
     to_arr: w=> w.split('_'),
     to_str: a=> a.map(w=>w.toLowerCase()).join('_')},

    {name: 'UpperCamel', pattern: /^([A-Z][a-z]*)+$/g,
     to_arr: w=> w.match(/[A-Z][a-z]*/g),
     to_str: a=> a.map(_.capitalize).join('')},

    //...
];
```

So each `Case` needs a pattern to determine if a string is of that scheme, a `to_arr` to split the string approprioately, and a `to_str` to join an array of words into a string of that scheme (`name` is optional, but it's good to be descriptive).  I've included those two becuase it's in the conversion from `lower_kebab` to `UpperCamel` where I'm getting some unexpected behavior.

I've implemented the actual conversion function like so:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.17.3/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.17.3/lodash.fp.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(()=>{

  var CASES = [
    
    { name: 'lower_kebab', pattern: /^[a-z]+(_[a-z]+)*$/g,
      to_arr: w=> w.split('_'),
      to_str: a=> a.map(w=>w.toLowerCase()).join('_')
    },
     
    { name: 'UpperCamel', pattern: /^([A-Z][a-z]*)+$/g,
      to_arr: w=> w.match(/[A-Z][a-z]*/g),
      to_str: a=> a.map(_.capitalize).join('')
    },
    
    //...
    
  ];
  
  function convert_to(target_scheme_example){
    return _.compose(
            CASES.find(c=>c.pattern.test(target_scheme_example)).to_str
    , str=> CASES.find(c=>c.pattern.test(str)).to_arr(str) );
  }
  
  $('#go').on('click', ()=> $('#result').text(
      convert_to( $('#dst').val() )( $('#src').val() )
  ));
  
});
 
</script>

<p>Try "<strong>UpperCamel</strong>" to "<strong>lower_kebab</strong>" and vice-versa.</p>
<input id="dst" value="UpperCamel" placeholder="Example of target scheme">
<input id="src" value="lower_kebab" placeholder="String to convert">

<button id="go">Convert</button>

<div>
  <p><strong>Result:</strong></p>
  <p id="result"></p>
</div>
```

The "real" version lives strictly in server-side code, so all that DOM-related stuff in the snippet is purely for demonstration purposes (the "real" version also does a little error checking using `_.get` which I excluded here for brevity).

**Here's where things get weird.**

On the server side, the problem manifests as `convert_to('UpCa')('activity_template')` evaluating to things like `"Activity_template"` and `"activity template"`. In the demo snippet, I believe the same issue is manifesting as only being able click "Convert" only once without throwing an exception.

Any thoughts? Are my RegExs a little off? Have I misunderstood how to use `_.compose`? If the tool were just broken, that'd be one thing, but it's really throwing me off how it works for many cases, but not all.

Comment: `CASES.find(c=>c.pattern.test(target_scheme_example)).to_str` doesn't retain anything about what object's `to_str` method it was in Javascript. It doesn't look like your `to_str`s need that info, though.

Comment: I assumed `compose` (or rather, the result of `compose`) would do that, i.e, in order to run `f(g(x))` I need to retain `f` and `g`. Is there a good way to get this effect?

Comment: Are you expecting that `_.compose(f, g)` will apply `f` before `g`? It kind of looks like you're expecting that.

Comment: I can see where it looks like that, but I think I have the order of the composition right. The first function to be applied (the last argument to `compose`) should be `f:String->Array`, which is the signature of `to_arr`. Similar story for the first argument, but with `to_str`

Comment: You're using `c=>c.pattern.test(str)` in the string->array part, which would require `str` to already match the pattern. Maybe you got `str` and `target_scheme_example` mixed up.

Comment: Hmm. That could be it. I'll play around with the ordering of the args.  https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=dzza0x26dH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation on `RegExp#test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test):

> `test()` called multiple times on the same global regular expression instance will advance past the previous match.

This is the reason why it only works the first time: the regular expression object (`pattern`) maintains state resulting from the previous execution of the `test` method on it.

To avoid this behaviour, you could do one of the following:

1. Remove the `g` modifiers from the `pattern` regular expressions, since they are not necessary for the kind of matching you are trying to do, or
2. Use the [`String#match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) method instead, swapping the position of the string and the regular expression:

   ```
   return _.compose(
       CASES.find(c=>target_scheme_example.match(c.pattern)).to_str
                , str=> CASES.find(c=>str.match(c.pattern)).to_arr(str) );
   }
   ```

Comment: I probably lulled myself into a false sense of security by setting `CASES` to `const` in the actual application. Removing the global flag from each case's pattern did the trick!

Comment: Indeed, `const` only prohibits re-assignment to the variable in question, not its mutation.